# Square matrix transpose in Javascript

Tags: javascript, matrix, transpose

I'm trying to create square matrix transpose function in Javascript, but it doesn't work as expected. Function:

```
function transpose(){
  var tmpCells = cells;

  for(var i=0; i<boardHeight; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<boardWidth; j++){
      tmpCells[i][j] = cells[j][i];
    }
  }
  cells =  tmpCells;
  clearCells();
  drawCells();
}
```

creates weird output. Instead of new 2D array of original size, it misses some cells and instead array of `objects` it creates array of different size with `circular bjects` inside. How this can be fixed and what I'm doing wrong?

JS fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Ls8jbho3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `tmpCells = cells` makes a new reference to an existing object rather than copying that object, `tmpCells[i][j] = cells[j][i]` is exactly the same as `cells[i][j] = cells[j][i]`. This is the source of all your problems.

Make sure your `tmpCells` does not share structure with `cells`, and the problem goes away:

```
function transpose(){
  var tmpCells = [];
  for(var i=0; i<boardHeight; i++){
    tmpCells[i] = [];
    for(var j=0; j<boardWidth; j++){
      tmpCells[i][j] = cells[j][i];
    }
  }
  cells =  tmpCells;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[mathjs](http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/transpose.html) can do this.
Here is the example :

```
var A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]];
math.transpose(A);               // returns [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```